# How to convert TIFF File to ASCII Hex to send ZPL to a Zebra Printer

Tags: vb.net, tiff, zpl

I am creating an application to dynamically print Labels to a networked Zebra printer. I can easily send text values but also need to include a logo at the bottom of the label. The logo(s) are stored on a network location and are tiff files.

I am struggling to find a good example of how to do this. The following code does print, but the returned string I receive from the file is purely FFFFF....  So all I am getting is a black rectangle.

```
Protected Sub Print()
    Dim IP As String = "172.16.132.92"
    Dim clientSocket As New Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp)
    clientSocket.Connect(New IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(IP), 9100))

    Dim bitmapFilePath As String = "\\SomeServer\Advertising\Artwork\Trademarks\Packaging Label Trademarks 8919\Betaplug.tif"
    Dim bitmapFileData As Byte() = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(bitmapFilePath)
    Dim fileSize As Integer = bitmapFileData.Length

    Dim bitmapDataOffset As Integer = 0
    Dim width As Integer = 50 '255
    Dim height As Integer = 50 '255
    Dim bitsPerPixel As Integer = 1
    Dim bitmapDataLength As Integer = 400
    Dim widthInBytes As Double = Math.Ceiling(width / 8.0)

    Dim bitmap(bitmapDataLength) As Byte

    For i As Integer = 0 To bitmapDataLength Step 1
        bitmap(i) = bitmap(i) Xor &HFF
    Next

    Dim ZPLImageDataString As String = BitConverter.ToString(bitmap)
    ZPLImageDataString = Replace(ZPLImageDataString, "-", String.Empty)

    Dim ZPL As String = "~DGR:SAMPLE.GRF," & bitmapDataLength & ",018," & _
                        ZPLImageDataString & _
                        "^XA" & _
                        "^F100,200^XGR:SAMPLE.GRF,2,2^FS" & _
                        "^XZ^"
    Dim Label As String = ZPL
    clientSocket.Send(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Label))
    clientSocket.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: This link may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29253453/how-to-print-a-logo-on-labels-using-a-zebra-printer-and-sending-zpl-instructions

Comment: I did this at an old job...I've got a copy of the code at home but won't be able to grab it for another few hours since I'm at work right now. But honestly, if you are only dealing with a couple of logos, it's much easier to just use http://labelary.com/viewer.html and add an image, get the zpl for it and just store that somewhere. But, in any case, if this question is still open when I get home I'll share what I have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I tackled this in the past. This code was pulled out of a drag&drop label designer so it has some conversions in it for handling differences in DPI which you'll have to remove if not needed. But the basic process was to get a bitmap, resize it so its width is divisible by 8 for encoding, make it monochrome since this was an on/off pixel thermal printer, convert its bits to a hex string, and then use ZPL's compression map to compress it (less we end up with a ridiculously long string that takes forever to send to the printer).

The 0.8 threshold is just a number I found to work pretty reliably, it is the cut-off value for deciding whether a bit is on/off depending on how dark it is, you may need to adjust that to suit your needs.

**Input Image was:**

[image]

**Output using Labelary's online ZPL viewer (http://labelary.com/viewer.html):**

[image]

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim imgZpl As String = TiffToZpl("C:\Users\sooho\Desktop\so.tif", 0.8)
        Debug.Print(imgZpl)
    End Sub

    Public Function TiffToZpl(tiffFilePath As String, grayscaleThreshold As Single) As String

        Dim ms As New System.IO.MemoryStream
        System.Drawing.Bitmap.FromFile(tiffFilePath).Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)
        Dim bmp = New System.Drawing.Bitmap(ms)

        ResizeBitmapMod8(bmp)
        bmp = Monochrome(bmp, grayscaleThreshold)

        Return BitmapToZpl(bmp, 0, 0)

    End Function

    Private Function BitmapToZpl(ByRef bm As Bitmap, top As Integer, left As Integer) As String
        Dim ret As New System.Text.StringBuilder
        Dim lastHexChar As Nullable(Of Char) = Nothing
        Dim hexCharCount As Integer = 0
        Dim finalHex As New System.Text.StringBuilder
        Dim bitCount As Integer = 0
        Dim binaryCount As Integer = 0
        For r As Integer = 0 To bm.Height - 1
            For c As Integer = 0 To bm.Width - 1
                bitCount += 1
                If Not bm.GetPixel(c, r).Name.Equals("ffffffff") Then
                    Select Case bitCount
                        Case 1 : binaryCount += 8
                        Case 2 : binaryCount += 4
                        Case 3 : binaryCount += 2
                        Case 4 : binaryCount += 1
                    End Select
                End If
                If bitCount = 4 Then
                    If lastHexChar Is Nothing Then
                        lastHexChar = CChar(hexMap(binaryCount))
                        hexCharCount = 1
                    Else
                        If CChar(hexMap(binaryCount)) = lastHexChar Then
                            hexCharCount += 1
                        Else
                            While hexCharCount > 0
                                Dim maxKey As Integer = 0
                                For Each key As Integer In zplHexCompressionMap.Keys
                                    If key <= hexCharCount Then
                                        maxKey = key
                                    Else
                                        Exit For
                                    End If
                                Next
                                finalHex.Append(zplHexCompressionMap(maxKey) & lastHexChar)
                                hexCharCount -= maxKey
                            End While
                            lastHexChar = CChar(hexMap(binaryCount))
                            hexCharCount = 1
                        End If
                    End If
                    bitCount = 0
                    binaryCount = 0
                End If
            Next c
        Next r
        While hexCharCount > 0
            Dim maxKey As Integer = 0
            For Each key As Integer In zplHexCompressionMap.Keys
                If key <= hexCharCount Then
                    maxKey = key
                Else
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
            finalHex.Append(zplHexCompressionMap(maxKey) & lastHexChar)
            hexCharCount -= maxKey
        End While

        Dim totalBytes As Integer = CInt((bm.Height * bm.Width) / 8)
        Dim byteWidth As Integer = CInt(bm.Width / 8)
        Dim adjustedLeft As Integer = CInt(left * dpiMultiplier_ScreenToPrinter)
        Dim adjustedTop As Integer = CInt(top * dpiMultiplier_ScreenToPrinter)

        ret.Append("^FO" & adjustedLeft.ToString & "," & adjustedTop.ToString)
        ret.Append("^GFA," & totalBytes.ToString & "," & totalBytes.ToString & "," & byteWidth.ToString & ",,")
        ret.Append(finalHex.ToString)
        ret.Append("^FS")

        Return ret.ToString
    End Function

    Private Sub ResizeBitmapMod8(ByRef bm As Bitmap)
        'Resizes a bitmap to its nearest width multiple of 8. Images must be hex-encoded
        'to be send to the printer, and hex encoding requires pairs of 4 bits, so the
        'the image's width must be divisible by 8 or the resulting image will have a black
        'strip down the side once it's decoded by the zpl printer
        If bm.Width Mod 8 <> 0 Then
            Dim width As Integer = bm.Width
            Dim height As Integer = bm.Height
            Dim aspectRatio As Double = width / height
            Dim lowMultiplier As Integer = CInt(Int(width / 8))
            Dim highMultiplier As Integer = lowMultiplier + 1
            Dim diffBelow As Integer = width - (lowMultiplier * 8)
            Dim diffAbove As Integer = (highMultiplier * 8) - width
            If diffBelow < diffAbove Then
                width = lowMultiplier * 8
            Else
                width = highMultiplier * 8
            End If
            height = CInt(width / aspectRatio)
            Dim bmResized As New Bitmap(width, height)
            Dim gfxResized As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmResized)
            gfxResized.DrawImage(bm, 0, 0, bmResized.Width + 1, bmResized.Height + 1)
            bm = bmResized
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Function Monochrome(ByVal bmOriginal As Bitmap, grayscaleThreshold As Single) As Bitmap
        Dim gsBitmap As New Bitmap(bmOriginal)

        Try
            'Convert image to grayscale
            Dim gfxSource As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(gsBitmap)
            Dim imgAttr As New System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageAttributes
            Dim imgRec As Rectangle = New Rectangle(0, 0, gsBitmap.Width, gsBitmap.Height)
            imgAttr.SetColorMatrix(New System.Drawing.Imaging.ColorMatrix(grayMatrix))
            imgAttr.SetThreshold(grayscaleThreshold)
            gfxSource.DrawImage(gsBitmap, imgRec, 0, 0, gsBitmap.Width, gsBitmap.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, imgAttr)
        Catch ex As Exception
            'image already has an indexed color matrix
        End Try

        'Convert format to 1-index monochrome
        Dim mcBitmap As Bitmap = New Bitmap(gsBitmap.Width, gsBitmap.Height, Imaging.PixelFormat.Format1bppIndexed)
        Dim mcBmData As Imaging.BitmapData = mcBitmap.LockBits(
            New Rectangle(0, 0, mcBitmap.Width, mcBitmap.Height),
            Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadWrite,
            Imaging.PixelFormat.Format1bppIndexed)
        For y As Integer = 0 To gsBitmap.Height - 1
            For x As Integer = 0 To gsBitmap.Width - 1
                Dim pixelColor As Color = gsBitmap.GetPixel(x, y)
                If pixelColor.Name = "ffffffff" Then
                    Dim index As Integer = y * mcBmData.Stride + (x >> 3)
                    Dim p As Byte = Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReadByte(mcBmData.Scan0, index)
                    Dim mask As Byte = CByte(&H80 >> (x And &H7))
                    p = p Or mask
                    Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.WriteByte(mcBmData.Scan0, index, p)
                End If
            Next x
        Next y
        mcBitmap.UnlockBits(mcBmData)

        Return mcBitmap
    End Function

    Public Const DPI_Screen As Double = 96
    Public Const DPI_Printer As Double = 203
    Public Const dpiMultiplier_ScreenToPrinter As Double = DPI_Printer / DPI_Screen
    Public grayMatrix()() As Single = {
        New Single() {0.299F, 0.299F, 0.299F, 0, 0},
        New Single() {0.587F, 0.587F, 0.587F, 0, 0},
        New Single() {0.114F, 0.114F, 0.114F, 0, 0},
        New Single() {0, 0, 0, 1, 0},
        New Single() {0, 0, 0, 0, 1}}
    Private hexMap() As String = {
        "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7",
        "8", "9", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"}
    Private zplHexCompressionMap As New SortedDictionary(Of Integer, Char) From {
        {1, "G"c}, {2, "H"c}, {3, "I"c}, {4, "J"c}, {5, "K"c},
        {6, "L"c}, {7, "M"c}, {8, "N"c}, {9, "O"c}, {10, "P"c},
        {11, "Q"c}, {12, "R"c}, {13, "S"c}, {14, "T"c}, {15, "U"c},
        {16, "V"c}, {17, "W"c}, {18, "X"c}, {19, "Y"c}, {20, "g"c},
        {40, "h"c}, {60, "i"c}, {80, "j"c}, {100, "k"c}, {120, "l"c},
        {140, "m"c}, {160, "n"c}, {180, "o"c}, {200, "p"c}, {220, "q"c},
        {240, "r"c}, {260, "s"c}, {280, "t"c}, {300, "u"c}, {320, "v"c},
        {340, "w"c}, {360, "x"c}, {380, "y"c}, {400, "z"c}}

End Class
```

Comment: after a fair amount of tweaking to fit my application.. It Works! Thank you very much.